# Codeigniter - view file -retrieve data from sql in batches

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

This is my response from model file through controller

```
array (size=2)
  'wholesale_records' => 
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[36]
      public 'id' => string '117' (length=3)
      public 'product_id' => string '60' (length=2)
      public 'usertype' => string 'wholesale' (length=9)
      public 'range' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'uom' => string '3' (length=1)
      public 'price' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'vat@' => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => 
    object(stdClass)[37]
      public 'id' => string '119' (length=3)
      public 'product_id' => string '60' (length=2)
      public 'usertype' => string 'wholesale' (length=9)
      public 'range' => string '3' (length=1)
      public 'uom' => string '3' (length=1)
      public 'price' => string '3' (length=1)
      public 'vat@' => string '3' (length=1)
  'wholesale_count' => int 2
```

But i want to display these in my input placeholder but i am getting error in displaying
this is my view file

```
<?php
for ( $i = 0; $i < $wholesale['wholesale_count']; $i ++ ) { ?>
    <div class="section row" id="row1" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="field">
                    <input type="text" name="range1" id="amount"
                           class="gui-input" placeholder="<?php echo $wholesale['wholesale_records'][ $i ]['range']; ?>"
                           required>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't show the controller or the model or the exact error you are getting. All would be very useful in providing help.  I'm going to make a guess at the problem. It's probably this line.

```
placeholder="<?php echo $wholesale['wholesale_records'][ $i ]['range']; ?>"
```

Your model is returning an array of objects so you need to use object notation to access the members

```
placeholder="<?php echo $wholesale['wholesale_records'][ $i]->range; ?>"
```

Which is frankly a whole lot harder than it needs to be.

Assuming that `$wholesale` is the response you show from the model you might want to consider this in your view.

```
<?php
$records = $wholesale['wholesale_records'];
foreach($records as $record){ ?>
  <div class="section row" id="row1" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="field">
          <input type="text" name="range1" id="amount"
                 class="gui-input" placeholder="<?php echo $record->range; ?>" required>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  <?php } ?>
```

Using `foreach(...)` is usually a lot easier to set up than a `for(...)` loop. It is not only less typing but it will execute faster.

It seems like model's return is maybe more complicated that it needs to be.
The model could simply finish with

```
return $query->result();
```

Which should return a structure like this

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[36]
      public 'id' => string '117' (length=3)
      public 'product_id' => string '60' (length=2)
      public 'usertype' => string 'wholesale' (length=9)
      public 'range' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'uom' => string '3' (length=1)
      public 'price' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'vat@' => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => 
    object(stdClass)[37]
      public 'id' => string '119' (length=3)
      public 'product_id' => string '60' (length=2)
      public 'usertype' => string 'wholesale' (length=9)
      public 'range' => string '3' (length=1)
      public 'uom' => string '3' (length=1)
      public 'price' => string '3' (length=1)
      public 'vat@' => string '3' (length=1)
```

You don't need bury the return another layer deep and you don't need 'wholesale_count'. The 'foreach` call will figure the count for you.

The controller could then passes the model return to view like so

```
$data['wholesale'] = $this->your_model->get_wholesale_records();
$this->load->view('your_view', $data);
```

Then the first couple lines in the view are reduced to

```
<?php
foreach($wholesale as $record){ ?>
    //the rest as shown previously
```